# creating dataframe from existing data frame columns and rows and insert data to new dataframe

Tags: r, optimization

I have dataframe called **PFV_Weekly** with 523 rows and 100 columns(No of columns will me increase later like 5000). 523 rows are having weekly dates and 100 columns are having ID's.

By using following code i have created a dataframe with 52300 rows.

```
PFV_Table <- data.table(matrix(nrow=nrow(List)*nrow(PriceData_Weekly), ncol=3))
```

Now i wish to insert the data for 3rd column by usifn original dataframe **PFV_Weekly**. Following code is been sued for the same.

```
k=1
for (i in 2:ncol(PFV_Weekly)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(PFV_Weekly)) {
    PFV_Table[k,1]<-as.character(names(PFV_Weekly)[i])
    PFV_Table[k,2]<-PFV_Weekly[j,1]
    PFV_Table[k,3]<-as.numeric(PFV_Weekly[j,i])
    k=k+1
  }
  print(i)
}
```

But this code is taking too much time to execute i want to make this code efficient. Please help.

As per the suggestion given i am adding the snipets of output i expect. 1st of all i will be adding snippet of input dataframe i.e. **PFV_Weekly**.
[image: Dataframe with Weekly Dates]

Then we can have look at the expected output dataframe i.e. **PFV_Table**
[image: Output Expected]

Hope this makes it more clear on what i expect to do.

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible example and show the expected output for the same?

Comment: Yes, pls add an example of some data. But generally speaking you should refrain from loops and rather use something like `PFV_Table[,3] <- PFV_Weekly[,5]`